# What is the correct way of managing transactionality in RxJava Services?

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android, netflix

I have recently started experimenting with RxJava and came across a presentation by a Netflix engineer that suggested moving our business APIs to Observable APIs, for instance:

```
public interface VideoService {
    Observable<VideoBasicInfo> createVideoBasicInfo(VideoBasicInfo videoBasic);
    Observable<VideoBasicInfo> getVideoBasicInfo(Integer videoId);
    Observable<VideoRating> getVideoRating(Integer videoId);
}
```

However I haven't found any place that explained how transactionality should be managed in this services. At first I just annotated my service implementation with `@Transactional`

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class VideoServiceImpl implements VideoService{

    @Autowired
    private VideoBasicInfoRepository basicInfoRepo;
    @Autowired
    private VideoRatingRepository ratingRepo;

    public Observable<VideoBasicInfo> createVideoBasicInfo(VideoBasicInfo videoBasic){
        return Observable.create( s -> {
            s.onNext(basicInfoRepo.save(videBasic));
        });
    }
```

What we would want is that the execution of all the code inside the `Object.create` lambda (`s -> { // This code }`) happened in a transaction. **HOWEVER**, what actually happens is that:

1. The call to `createVideoBasicInfo()` executes in a transactional way, returning the cold observable.
2. The `save()` executes as an atomic transaction.

Obviously it makes sense since the Spring proxy applies to the serviceImpl methods. I have thought of ways to do what I really expect such as starting a programmatic transaction:

```
return Observable.create( s -> {
    VideoBasicInfo savedBasic = transactionTemplate.execute( status -> {
        VideoBasicInfo basicInfo = basicInfoRepo.save(videoBasicInfo);
        return basicInfo;
    });
    s.onNext(savedBasic);
});
```

Is this the recommended way of managing transactions when working with reactive APIs?

Comment: What is your repository?  Is it an implementation of a Spring Data CrudRepository?  The CrudRepository has a "save" method that is marked transactional

Comment: Not to mention that once you use Observables, an api user can easily subscribe or observe on different threads, and Sping transactions and many other componentes rely on a per-thread behavior, using thread-local variables. Using RxJava with complex Spring Transactions might prove to be complicated, but now that Spring 5 is given support for Spring Reactor I'd to learn how this is supposed to work too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring Data JpaRepository method signatures are already marked @Transactional, so if you are using just one then you don't need to do anything special:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
}
```

---

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {RepositoryConfiguration.class})
public class PersonRepositoryTest {
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setPersonRepository(PersonRepository PersonRepository) {
        this.personRepository = PersonRepository;
    }

    @Test
    public void testReactiveSavePerson() {
        Person person = new Person("Jane", "Doe");
        assertNull(person.getId()); //null before save

        //save person
        Observable.create(s -> {
            s.onNext(personRepository.save(person));
        }).subscribe();

        //fetch from DB
        Person fetchedPerson = personRepository.findOne(person.getId());

        //should not be null
        assertNotNull(fetchedPerson);

        //should equal
        assertEquals(person.getId(), fetchedPerson.getId());
        assertEquals(person.getFirstName(), fetchedPerson.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

If you need to combine multiple repositories into one transaction, you could use something like the class below:

```
@Component()
public class ObservableTxFactory {
    public final <T> Observable<T> create(Observable.OnSubscribe<T> f) {
        return new ObservableTx<>(this, f);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void call(Observable.OnSubscribe onSubscribe, Subscriber subscriber) {
        onSubscribe.call(subscriber);
    }

    private static class ObservableTx<T> extends Observable<T> {

        public ObservableTx(ObservableTxFactory observableTxFactory, OnSubscribe<T> f) {
            super(new OnSubscribeDecorator<>(observableTxFactory, f));
        }
    }

    private static class OnSubscribeDecorator<T> implements Observable.OnSubscribe<T> {

        private final ObservableTxFactory observableTxFactory;
        private final Observable.OnSubscribe<T> onSubscribe;

        OnSubscribeDecorator(final ObservableTxFactory observableTxFactory, final Observable.OnSubscribe<T> s) {
            this.onSubscribe = s;
            this.observableTxFactory = observableTxFactory;
        }

        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
            observableTxFactory.call(onSubscribe, subscriber);
        }
    }
}
```

The factory bean needs to be defined as well:

```
@Bean
ObservableTxFactory observableTxFactory() {
    return new ObservableTxFactory();
}
```

---

Service:

```
@Service
public class PersonService {
    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;
    @Autowired
    ObservableTxFactory observableTxFactory;

    public Observable<Person> createPerson(String firstName, String lastName) {
        return observableTxFactory.create(s -> {
            Person p = new Person(firstName, lastName);
            s.onNext(personRepository.save(p));
        });
    }
}
```

---

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {RepositoryConfiguration.class})
public class PersonServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;
    @Autowired
    ObservableTxFactory observableTxFactory;

    @Test
    public void testPersonService() {
        final PersonService service = new PersonService();
        service.personRepository = personRepository;
        service.observableTxFactory = observableTxFactory;

        final Observable<Person> personObservable = service.createPerson("John", "Doe");
        personObservable.subscribe();

        //fetch from DB
        final Person fetchedPerson = StreamSupport.stream(personRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
                .filter(p -> p.getFirstName().equals("John") && p.getLastName().equals("Doe"))
                .findFirst()
                .get();

        //should not be null
        assertNotNull(fetchedPerson);
    }

}
```

Screenshot showing proxy:
[image]

Comment: Hi John, they are Spring Data JpaRepositositories. However what I want to achieve is transactionality in the service layer, that is to say to call several DAOs within the same transaction. It can be done with transactionTemplate but I was wondering if there is an alternative

Comment: JpaRepository is a subclass of CrudRepository; in this example its effectivley the same. So you want several repositories to be involved in the same transaction?  That isn't the problem stated in your question... You wrote: "What we would want is that the execution of basicInfoRepo.save() happened in a transaction."

Comment: I updated the code to show the service implementation and test

Comment: Hi John, I just tested your solution but it doesn't work. Notice that `ObservableTx.create` actually calls `Observable.create` which invokes `return new Observable<T>(hook.onCreate(f));`, so a new ObservableTx is never created. Also, It's very likely that although `@Transactional ObservableTx.call` were invoked it would not be transactional since it is not a Spring bean. It comes from a constructor call.

Comment: I added `public final static <T> ObservableTx<T> createTx(OnSubscribe<T> f) {
        return new ObservableTx<T>(hook.onCreate(f));
    }` and verified that call() doesn't execute transactionally.

Comment: @WornOutSoles thanks for the feedback. I reworked the implementation. Hopefully, this is sufficient for your case and you can accept the answer...

Comment: Any luck with this answer?

Comment: Just tried it and works perfectly. Thank you for taking the time to provide this solution.

Comment: This solution it's flawed, it adds the transactional boundary at the moment of starting the subscription instead of adding the transactional boundary into the `Subscriber` behaviour. The former works in this case because we have here a cold Observable, but it won't work with a hot one because elements may not be emitted on the same thread that subscribes.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to piggyback on [John Scattergood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5672880/john-scattergood)'s excellent answer. My typical usage is with the `Observable.fromCallable()` so I was looking for a way to do that instead of implementing the `Observable.OnSubscribe` so I adapted his technique so that you can use it by passing in a `Callable`

Factory Class:

```
@Component
public class ObservableTxFactory {
    public final <T> Observable.OnSubscribe<T> createFromCallable(Callable<? extends T> resultFactory) {
        return new OnSubscribeDecorator<>(this, resultFactory);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public <T> void call(Callable<? extends T> resultFactory, Subscriber subscriber) {
        final SingleDelayedProducer<T> singleDelayedProducer = new SingleDelayedProducer<>(subscriber);

        subscriber.setProducer(singleDelayedProducer);

        try {
            singleDelayedProducer.setValue(resultFactory.call());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Exceptions.throwOrReport(t, subscriber);
        }
    }

    private static class OnSubscribeDecorator<T> implements Observable.OnSubscribe<T> {

        private final ObservableTxFactory observableTxFactory;
        private final Callable<? extends T> resultFactory;

        OnSubscribeDecorator(final ObservableTxFactory observableTxFactory, Callable<? extends T> resultFactory) {
            this.resultFactory = resultFactory;
            this.observableTxFactory = observableTxFactory;
        }

        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
            observableTxFactory.call(resultFactory, subscriber);
        }
    }
}
```

Original Code:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> fooRepository.findOne(fooID));
```

New Code:

```
Observable.create(observableTxFactory.createFromCallable(() -> fooRepository.findOne(fooID)));
```

**Make sure that the method you add `@Transactional` on is `public` otherwise Spring AOP will NOT be able to advise it**